# PHP download large files fail on slow connection

Tags: php, download, iis-7.5

I have a server running Windows 2008R2, IIs7.5 and PHP 5.3.8 (as a FastCGI application). 
I have written a PHP download script to download large files (roughly 2.5 GB's). The script reads the files in 100K chunks to reduce the memory overhead on the server. On "normal" bandwidth links the download works fine. On slow links however (roughly less than 4 mbit), the downloads terminate without any reason. I cannot find any clue in the PHP error log, the IIS log or the event logs of the machine. I have ruled out any other components like firewall, proxy server. 
My first hunch was a simple PHP timeout, but even with the script starting with `set_time_limit (86400); //24 hours`
it still fails after somewhere between one and two hours. The timeout does not appear to happen at the exact same moment every time.
I am completely lost, can someone shed a light please?

Comment: I would still hazard that IIS is set up to terminate connections taking > 4 hours.

Comment: where can I alter (or at least check) the IIS timeout?

Comment: Under the specific website, I found the Connection Limits under Advanced Settings. I altered the Connection Time-Out from 300 to 900 (I expect a 100K chunk to be easily transferred in 900 seconds) but that made no difference. 
What timeout (of four hours) are you referring to?